# Change Elements in React via props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props

I want to make a simple react component that gets sent a value between 1 and 5, then render a progress bar with 5 "sections" but only have the amount sent be colored in, if that makes sense. I made this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-night-nnc4y8?file=/src/App.js) to demonstrate what I mean. So for example if I pass a value of 3 in app.js, I want it to only light up 3 of the bars green in my progress.js component.

One way I was thinking about doing it is somehow removing the progress-bar-empty className from only the first 3 sections(or however many I decide to pass to the props) or using a loop- but I can't use .map since it's not an array I think. As you can probably tell, I'm still fairly new to web development especially JavaScript and React, so thank you for your patience and understanding, sorry if the answer is really obvious. Hopefully this question can help others out there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question, You just need to create a random Array which contains five element, then you use method `Array.map` to check whether the `props.value` is large than `index` then return element as `progress-bar` and other as `progress-bar-empty`

```
export default function Progress(props) {
  console.log(props.value);
  return (
    <div className="progress col">
      {Array(5).fill('').map((_, index) =>
        index < props.value ? (
          <div className="progress-bar"></div>
        ) : (
          <div className="progress-bar progress-bar-empty"></div>
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about making a random array with array(5).fill. You taught me something new :) Have a great day!

Comment: @Isabelle I use `Array(5).fill('')` since i dont know what should i put in, it is the same as `['','','','','']`. If the answer helps please [mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A&text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)

Answer (score 0):

For example you can implement it in this way:

```
export default function Progress({ value }) {
  return (
    <div className="progress col">
      {Array.from({ length: 5 }).map((_, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          className={
            index < value ? "progress-bar" : "progress-bar progress-bar-empty"
          }
        ></div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```